# How to display response data using react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, rabbitmq

I'm making a project using rabbitMQ and react.

I did connect rabbitMQ server and my react app, and I finally success get some data from server.

I can print those data in console (like using console.log()), however I cannot display data in html.

I tried to use async/await but it didn't work.

```
function ServerTest() {

var a:any;
const client = createClient("admin", "1111");
    const queue = v4();
    

    client.onConnect = function () {
        console.log("connected to Stomp");

        subscribe(client, 'admin', queue, (payload: {}) => {              
            a = payload;
            a = a.UserInfo.userId
            console.log(a)
        })

        publish(client, 'api.user.info', 'admin', queue, {})

    }

    client.activate();

    
    return (<div>a: {a}</div>)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React does not listen for changes happening in any random variable, be it variable `a`, so the UI will not be updated automatically. To get the desired functionality, `useState` hook can be used here.

For that, import the useState function.

```
import {useState} from 'react'
```

Inside the function, use it like this

```
function ServerTest() {

const [ valueA, setValueA ] = useState();
```

An initial value for valueA can also be passed

```
const [ valueA, setValueA ] = useState(initialState);
```

`valueA` will hold the current state, so use it in the return statement

```
return (<div>a: {valueA}</div>)
```

Now, when data from the server is available, use `setValueA` to update the value of `valueA`

```
subscribe(client, 'admin', queue, (payload: {}) => {              
            setValueA(payload.UserInfo.userId);
```

By doing this, react will automatically update the UI to match the current state of 'valueA'

Answer (score 0):

If this is in your react component, you should use state to show the value from the api.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
const MyComponent = () => {
   const [aState, setA] = useState();

   const callApi = () => {
   //get values from API here
   setA(apiValue);
}
return (
   <div>{aState}</div>
)
```

In your code, return the `a` value you get from the api and then pass it into `setA(a)`. When the `aState` value changes, the component will automatically rerender and the result will be shown on the page.